# Use ManipulationDelta event of webbrowser control to scroll a listbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have multiple webbrowser controls inside a listBox (Hierarchy: DataBoundListBox->Multiple ExpandableItems->Each expandable item shows a webbrowser control on expansion.).

The problem is, the webbrowser control captures the drag gesture and it is impossible to scroll the listbox once the webbrowser control is expanded. If the content of the webbrowser is too long, the user is stuck and cannot scroll anymore as the webbrowser fill the entire screen. Now, the webbrowser only needs to respond to simple tap events (buttons).

The webbrowser control captures all touch gestures and events internally, but it seems that there is a `border` element where touch events can be intercepted before the touch gestures reach the `tilehost` and is gone forever:

`Border border = WebViewer.Descendants<Border>().Last() as Border;`

To capture the touch gesture, I added a ManipulationDelta event to the border as it does not allow me to add a Gesture Listener event like `DragStarted`, `DragDelta`, `DragCompleted`.

Now I need to get this ManipulationDelta event data to the scrollviewer inside the listbox where the browser is located.

Is this a valid conceptual approach and is somebody able to help me on how to get this running?

P.S.: I tried it the other way around (sending tap gesture events from a canvas overlay to a javascript inside the webbrowser control page and simulate a tap on the page) but this does not seem to work very well as the touch coordinates and the javascript coordinates have a unknown offset.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Did so. I am so amazed that it works, I hope it helps other people as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the last method with javascript was actually working quite well, the problem was the double x and y value which was passed to the javascript. After converting it to integer, it detected the underlying html element pixel precise.

If you want to know how you can transfer tap events to a website in a webbrowser element, you need to do the following:

Add "LinqToVisualTree" to your project and your document (f.e.: using LinqToVisualTree;)!

Add this javascript code to your website (besides jquery):

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();}
```

Add silverlight toolkit (search for GestureService for info) to your solution and add this event to the overlay canvas (the canvas element which is placed over the webbrowser element) in the XAML file (example, note the canvas I put also in there. You would have to replace it with your own canvas or grid or whatever:

```
<Canvas>
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener  Tap="GestureListener_Tap"/>
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
</Canvas>
```

Add this to your xaml file codebehind c# (note that I did a little recalculation of the original coordinates from the tap, you may have to change the number 1.3499. This is the static offset factor of the buttons on the emulator.):

```
    private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas cv = sender as Canvas;
        //!!! You need to change the following search for the webbrowser to your own    xaml structure.
        // It uses "LinqToVisualTree" to find the element! Add it to your document!
        WebBrowser wb = cv.Ancestors<Grid>().First().ElementsBeforeSelf<WebBrowser>().First() as WebBrowser;
        var gesture = e.GetPosition(cv);
        var gx = gesture.X;
        var gy = gesture.Y;
        tapBrowser(wb, gx, gy);
    }

    private static void tapBrowser(WebBrowser wb, double x, double y)
    {
        GeneralTransform gt = wb.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
        Point offset = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        double rx = (x / 1.3499);
        double ry = (y / 1.3499);
        int ix = (int)rx;
        int iy = (int)ry;
        wb.InvokeScript("simulateClick", ix.ToString(), iy.ToString());
    }
```

Make sure your canvas has the same size as the webbrowser element!

Thats it. You now have a tap enabled browser but you can keep the rest of the gestures inside the native app and the browser won't catch them! Theoretically, you can redirect more gestures, but you need to have a javascript/jquery function which can "resimulate" the gesture you want to pass on.